# Changing a div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I already fail at a seemingly basic task in javascript - changing a div's content by a script. Please help me understand where I am going wrong. Here is a minimal example that's not working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="id" >blub</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: move the `<script>` section after your div, or call it on window.load event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML files load starting at the top to the bottom of the html.

In your example, the javascript executes before the `<body>` tag exists in the DOM.

Moving the javascript to below the relevant html makes it work as you would expect.

Another option would be to keep the script inside the `<head>` but delay it from executing until the DOM is loaded

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div id="id" >blub</div>

    <script>
      document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem with you code it that the JavaScript code is executed before the div part is loaded fully. To fix this change you code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changeDiv()
            {
                document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="changeDiv();">
        <div id="id" >blub</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The onload event will only fire when the html is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>


   </head>

    <body>
       <div id="id" >blub</div>
       <script>
          document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
      </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

put your script after the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.onload to call your code when html is fully loaded:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "test";
            };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="id" >blub</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Dom is no not loaded.. Place your script tag at the end before

Answer (score 0):

Just add the script tag before closing the body. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the Javascript after the div-Tag. First the DOM needs to be loaded and after you can change the content inside the DIV.

Place your Javascript before the closing-body Tag